# Pass Value from Button back to C# Controller from ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two buttons on my cshtml page - `Agree` and `Disagree` - how can I easily pass back there values to my Controller so I can make a decision to either take them to Homepage or Log them back out.

So on my cshtml page I have...

```
    <input type="button" name='Agree' value="I Agree"
                   onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DoAccept", "Home")'" />
    <input type="button" name='Delete' value="I Disagree"
                   onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DoAccept", "Home")'" />
```

So In my Home Controller then I have a DoAccept method as below:

```
    public ActionResult DoAcceptTC()
    {
       //if( buttom clicked was Agree)
        return RedirectToAction(VIEW_HOMEPAGE);
       //else
      //return Logout page..  
    }
```

So My question is how can I easily get a value back to the controller method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no much point in using inputs without html form hosting them. You could use form, or simple links

```
//view
@using(Html.BeginForm("DoAccept"))
{
     <button name="decision" value="agree">I Agree</button>
     <button name="decision" value="disagree">I disagree</button>
}

//controller
public ActionResult DoAcceptTC(string decision)
{
    //decision == "agree"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must send paramaters along with Url.Action to the controller so that you can be able to perform your actions easily. Below link may help you.

[Url.Action with params](http://geekswithblogs.net/liammclennan/archive/2008/05/21/122298.aspx)